# Open every link in loop (Selenium)

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I just cracked my head trying to find how make it work. I am trying to force `Selenium` open `link` by `link`, but it opens on first link again and again, console output shows that loop is working correctly. Tried to use while loop but it doesn`t work too. I am trying to open link after link and change number of the li element to open further link.

```
for (int footer_links = 1; footer_links < 6; footer_links++) {
    WebElement self_service_bi = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div/ul/li['$footer_links']/a"));
    self_service_bi.click();
    File srcFile1 = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    File targetFile1 = new File("D:\\DataPineScreenshots\\" + driver.getTitle() + ".png");
    FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile1, targetFile1);
    driver.navigate().back();
    System.out.print(footer_links + "\n");
}
```

Comment: What is the `exception`? `StaleElementReferenceExxception`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`driver.findElement` will always return the first element of the type. Use `driver.findElements` function to get list of all matching the given xpath. **But dont do that in loop cause everytime it will open the same link.**
Try out like:

```
List<String> lstUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
List<WebElement> lstEle = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div/div/ul/li['$footer_links']/a"));
for (WebElement element : lstEle)
    lstUrls.add(element.getAttribute("href"));

for (String string : lstUrls) {
    driver.get(string)
    File srcFile1 = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    File targetFile1 = new File("D:\\DataPineScreenshots\\" +  driver.getTitle() + ".png");
    FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile1, targetFile1);
    driver.navigate().back();
    System.out.print(footer_links + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

fix your syntax

```
By.xpath("//div/div/ul/li['$footer_links']/a")
```

by

```
By.xpath("//div/div/ul/li[" + footer_links + "]/a")
```

Comment: I think it does provide an answer to the question