# visit all links and sublinks on webpage using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

i have a webpage starts with 4 links and each link has 2 or more links and those links also has 1 or 2 links and so on, So how can i visit all links and nested links using selenium and python?

all links has same relative xpath

i have tried below code but it's not working

```
urls = {}

def visit_children(locator_path):
    children = get_children(locator_path)
    time.sleep(1)
    if children == 1:        
        click_func(locator_path)
        visit_children(locator_path)
    elif children > 1:
        print(children)
        time.sleep(2)
        url = driver.current_url
        print(url)
        urls[url] = children
        print(urls)
        for i in range(children):
            child_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(locator_path)
            child_elements[i].click()
            time.sleep(2)
            visit_children(locator_path)                
    else:
         for link,no_elements in urls.items():
                if urls[driver.current_url] > 0:
                    driver.get(link)
                    time.sleep(1)
                    urls[driver.current_url] -= 1
                    print(urls)
                    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open every link in loop (Selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011751/open-every-link-in-loop-selenium)

Comment: @DMart i have flow like binary tree and can only solve by dfs but i don't know how to do it in selenium you can refer to same kind of question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64884227/traverse-links-and-sub-links-by-clicking-on-elements-selenium-python

Comment: recursion won't work here as you'd need a new driver/thread for each level.  I thought about this a bit and I think what you want is an array that eats itself up as you go.  One array that stores all.... another for driver gets. (the eatup array) Each time you use a get you remove that link from the array.  Add found links two both arrays but only if they don't exist in the "all" array.   Then "gobble up" the next member of the driver gets array.  You are done when the gets array = zero.

Comment: ...and this would be easier if you are able to use .get()s instead of .click()s.  A good amount of sites these days don't allow for bookmarking, so you'd need to use a click... which means you'd need to store the procedure to get to your .click()s along with the click()...

Comment: @pcalkins I don't think we need a new driver for each level but if you meant we have to find the element again for each loop, yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is to implement a crawler, to do that you will need 2 data structures there, one to tell you what urls you have already visited and another where you just dump extract urls based in your criteria.

The crawler function just needs to pop the first URL from the of urls, check if it's a URL that you have already crawled and if not crawl it.

Something like this:

```
visited = {}
urls = ['initial_url']  

while len(urls) > 0:
  url = urls.pop()
  if visited[url] == 1:
    continue
  crawl(url)
```

Notice that set's have a O(1) complexity so you might want to use them to quickly confirm if you have already visited a url or not, while lists (FIFO) while be a awesome way to store the extracted urls.